# HTML CSS position div left center right

Tags: html, css

I have navigation bar:
[nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9etNr.png)
I read many stackoverflow articles about positioning left-middle-center of 3 div elements and I like this way but it's kinda not perfect and I don't know why:

```
     <div class="topnav">
             <div class="topnav-left">
                 <a href="/">Home</a>
             </div>
             <div class="topnav-center">
                 <a href="/about-me">Logo</a>
             </div>
             <div class="topnav-right">
                 <a href="/login">Login</a>
             </div>

     </div>
```

style.css

```
.topnav{
    text-align: center;}
.topnav-left{
    float:left;}
.topnav-right{
    float:right;}
.topnav-center{
    display: inline-block;}
```

The problem is, when I redirect to same page with only Home and Logo (so no right part) the logo moves a little bit to the right, like it was dependant on the existence of a right part. Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this with CSS flexbox. Read more [about CSS flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Add this CSS to `.topnav`:

```css
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
```

What is it doing? It is making sure that the remaining space between the container's children (in this case the three divs inside) are distributed evenly.

One small sidenote, using `float` for positioning elements is not considered a best practice (anymore).

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  /* Styling */
  background: #eee;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

/* Styling */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-left">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav-center">
    <a href="/about-me">Logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Solution with left and center element, you just need to have an empty `div` for the right part. See below snippet for result.

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* Styling */
  background: #eee;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.topnav-left,
.topnav-right {
  flex: 1;
}


/* Styling */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-left">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav-center">
    <a href="/about-me">Logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I have only Home left and Logo center can I use flexbox too?